# How to invert horizontal scrolling Apple Mouse

Tags: macos, mouse

I understand that I must disable Natural scrolling (but it inverses up and down scrolling as well) But it doesn't help I want just inverse left to right to left scrolling.

Comment: Why? Surely you've not become accustomed to that?

Comment: @benwiggy seems legit to me: those used to ipad horizontal scrolling would be just as confused with Left and Right controls and Up and Down

Comment: @cmason exactly

Comment: @cmason But doesn't default scrolling on macOS mirror the behaviour of an iPad? I use a trackpad, and it's exactly the same swipes as on an iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [article](https://osxdaily.com/2011/09/26/reverse-horizontal-scrolling-in-mac-os-x/), this software is suggested: [Scroll Reverser](https://pilotmoon.com/scrollreverser/)

[image: Horizontal scroll]